# remove row index from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe named 'df'

```
       h      w    x      y
5   21.0  208.0  7.0  270.0
20  34.0  209.0  0.0  158.0
```

I want to get a single cell out of this dataframe. Forthat I did:

```
X=df.x
print(X)
```

This is how x in data frame appears when I do df.x

```
5     7.0
20    0.0
```

My expected output is.

```
7.0
0.0
```

How do I get my expected output?  Please note: (I referred to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html and found out that by doing `df.at[5, 'x']` I can get the values. But I donot want this as  I will have to manually enter `5` the index of the row each time to get the value of x I want somethig wich will output value of x as it is without appending any other number to it)

Comment: `print(df['x'].to_string(index=False))` use`index=False`

Comment: What is reason for it? Write to file?

Comment: yes I want to write these values to a file